# How to run multiple files in python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, file, memory

so title doesn't explain much.
I have a function where it should run on a separate .py file.

So I have a python file where it takes some variables and waits for event to happen than continue until it finishes. You can think this as event listener (web socket).
This file runs and doesn't give output just does some functions and when event finishes it closes. So running one file only is no problem but I want to run more than 10 of these at the same time for different purposes but same event, this causes problems where some of them doesn't work or miss the event. 
I do this by running 10 terminals (cmd or shell). Which I think it creates problem because of running this much of event handling in shells, in future I might use more than 10 files maybe 50-100.

So what I tried:

- I tried one-file using threading (multi-threading) and it didn't work.

My goal 
I want help with this problem where I can run as many as these files without missing events and slowing down the system. I am open to ideas.

Comment: Can't you import them?

Comment: Import what file ?

Comment: You have a .py file that you would like to run multiple times, don't you?

Comment: Yes but inside that file there is one variable that change every time.

Comment: You can import the function/class/whatever, and run it multiple times. The variable could have different value regarding of how you running the function. It would help if you could share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Concurrent.future` could be a good option, it execute a piece of
  code in another thread. See documentation
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html.
- The `threading` library that comes with Python allows you to start
  mutliple times the same function in different threads whithout having
  to wait for them to finish. See the documentation
  ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.
- A similar API is in the library `multiprocessing` allow you do the
  same in pultiple processes. Documentation is
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html. One
  difference is that in Python threads are virtual, all manage in the
  single interpreter process. With `multiprocessing` you start several
  processes and probably have less impact on the performance.

The code you have to run in a process or a thread has to be in a defined function. It seems that this code is in a separate .py file, a module, therefore you have to import it (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) first. So one file manage the thread/multiprocess in a loop, another for the code listening the event and only one terminal will be required to start them.

Comment: Thanks that really helped out but can you explain the last sentence a bit more, because I am lost. Here what I understand, I will create module with my .py file then in another file I will run multiprocess which this file will be the one terminal ? thanks.

Comment: The `.py` files i.e. the modules are not a constraint. I understood from your question that you have a separated file when you are talking about a separate file .py but all the code can be in one file. It depends on your constraints. Please see this example in a gist https://gist.github.com/phe-sto/0e574c3e6a7a96f49b6154b0182e3ad9 it might help you. Just fill the code in `def my_awesome_code` with your code and it will surely do the trick.

Comment: Wow This really helped out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi Threading.
here in this page you will find some very useful examples of what you want (I recommend using the `concurrent.futures` cause in the new version of python 3 you will run into some bugs using the `threading` ).
https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#using-a-threadpoolexecutor

Comment: Thanks, I did use threading but not concurrent.futures, will give it a try!